# oracle database contains with "in%"

Tags: oracle

While working with one of the oracle query, when i am firing a select command with where condition something like:

```
select * from table_name where contains(address,'"IN%" AND "BÖDEN%"') >0
```

No results are shown as part of this query though results are there in database.

Again if i introduce one space between "IN" and "%" i am getting results in proper:

```
select * from table_name where contains(address,'"IN %" AND "BÖDEN%"') >0
```

There is one more scenario :

Same type of query but if "IN" is replaced with "IM" the corresponding results are displayed.

```
select * from table_name where contains(address,'"IM%" AND "BÖDEN%"') >0
```

or

```
select * from table_name where contains(address,'"IM %" AND "BÖDEN%"') >0
```

Both above queries are giving same results. which is quite obvious too.

Hence i suspect there is something speacial with "IN" in oracle.

Can anybody suggest me proper reason for this problem and any resolution for the problem ?

Answer (score 3):

The IN keyword is a stop word in the default Stoplist which is used to specify the words which are not be indexed in Oracle Text.

You need to remove it from the stop list in order to search such stop words.

Check the link for [**Stoplist**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A91202_01/901_doc/text.901/a90121/cdatadi9.htm)

Also please find the other default Stop words for English in oracle for your reference [**Default Stop words**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A91202_01/901_doc/text.901/a90121/astopsu2.htm#43324)